# Searching for a Russian SF novel or short story

Tags: novel, story-identification

Can anybody help me to find an older Sci-Fi novel from Russia from the 70's or 80's?

It's about a group of astronauts exploring the galaxy (or even the whole universe) for new planets and life forms. In their expeditions, they use some kind of wormholes for traveling  to explore the universe and also return to Earth.

The story starts with the return of the astronauts from their first expedition. They insert their ships into Earth's orbit before getting the permission from mission control to enter the Earth's atmosphere. Everything seems normal until the astronauts notices that everything in their ship is mirror-inverted. Before their expedition, all the buttons which were right are now on the left side of the cockpit for example.

It's some kind of pole reversal and all the ships and the crew within become anti-matter itself, most likely because of the worm hole. So mission control forbid all ships involved to return to Earth and even orders them to leave the solar system and never to return, for the sake of all.

My father read this novel in his youth in the Russian language, so some information may be wrong.
Nevertheless, I hope that you will be able to help me find the name of the author and the book.

Comment: WOW, Thats it! My father saw the title "Door From The Other Side by Vladimir Mikhailov (1974) (Дверь с той стороны, В. Михайлов)" and remembered. Thank you so much!